# How to change the date in a range under certain conditions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to change one or more dates to the current date under certain conditions using a button?

In my example table, the tab "Home" contains a list of users and the number of checks to be performed (column O "To Check").

In the tab "Ticker Check" there is also the column A "User ID", the column I "Last check" and the column L "Next check". The next check is calculated on the basis of various factors that are not important at this point.

Now I would like to add a button to the tab "Home" for each user to set all dates of column I "last check" in the tab "Ticker check" to the current date, where the date of column L "next check" in the respective row is either today or in the past (in the example table the relevant cells are colored red due to the conditional formatting). This means that dates that are still in the future should remain unaffected.

Note: In column J a timestamp is generated by a script, which I append below. Among other things, this timestamp is triggered by entries in the tab "Ticker Check" in column I "Last check". It is therefore important to me that this function is not disturbed.

Unfortunately I don't have enough programming knowledge. Therefore I would be very grateful for a solution from which I can learn.

This is the link to my sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z8Yom8oyfK8YVljndw1mSicdzkokbfCxm_U1vKSJk9k/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+2";
  var timestamp_format = "HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "date";
  var updateColName1 = "Monat"; // define your 2nd column
  var timeStampColName = "timestamp";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet() 
  //var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Geprüfte Ticker'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }

  //add code to update time/date stamp if the additionally defined columns have changes
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName1); updateCol = updateCol+1;

  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if ‘Last Updated’ header exists, but not in the header row itself!
  var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
  cell.setValue(date);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The workflow would be the following:

1. Retrieve the date of today with `var today=new Date()`
2. Compare the dates in column L against today by comparing the values in milliseconds with `getTime()`
3. Set today's date in column I for the row where the condition "date not in the future" is fulfilled and where the value in column A corresponds to the desired user ID within a `for loop`
4. Create a button e.g. with `Insert Drawing`, right-click on the button, select `Assign script...` and inserting the name of the function to be run on button click, as illustrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDMY9o23uBM).

Here is how you could implement it:

```
function myButton1(){
  var userId=1;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tickerCheck = ss.getSheetByName('Ticker Check');
  var startRow=12;
  var lastRow=tickerCheck.getLastRow()-startRow+1;
  var range=tickerCheck.getRange(startRow,12,lastRow,1)// getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
  var valuesNextCheck=range.getValues();
  var userIds=tickerCheck.getRange(startRow,1,lastRow,1).getValues();
  var rangeLastCheck=tickerCheck.getRange(startRow,9,lastRow,1);
  var today=new Date();
  var dateInMs=new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()).getTime();
  for(var i=0;i<valuesNextCheck.length;i++){
   var nextDate=valuesNextCheck[i][0]
   if((nextDate instanceof Date)&&(userIds[i][0]==userId)){
     if(dateInMs>=nextDate.getTime()){
         rangeLastCheck.getCell(i+1, 1).setValue(today);
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

For the other users, create the functions `myButton2()` and `myButton3()`, adjust `userId` accordingly,  and bind the functions to the respective buttons.

> Reference: [Date objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

Comment: Wow! this is great and almost exactly what I need. Is it possible to change only the dates from a single user (see from column A12)? The thing is, that the users should be able to change the dates only for their own rows. Therefor I want to place for each user a button at the Tab "Home" column Q. In my final sheet there are up to 40 users.

Comment: If you want to create a separate button for each user, you will need to create a slightly modified function for each user, see my updated answer. If you have many users though, you might think about other solutions, like implementing a dynamic dialog / sidebar where the user will be prompted to enter his Id that will be passed to the function.

Comment: When I start the script I get an reference error: "userID" is not defined. However, thats a good suggestion to implement a dynamic prompt. How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled the variable name, it should be either in both cases userID, or in both userId. I just changed it in my code.

Comment: No problem. I'm very grateful for your help. Unfortunately my timestamp script doesn't recognize the changes made by the myButton1 script in column I. What is the reason for this?

My timestamp script registers changes in the columns H or I and then creates a timestamp in column J, which is needed for the calculation of my formula in column L. 
How can this be fixed?

Comment: You mean your timestamp script is bound to an onEdit trigger? Unfortunately this trigger is fired only by human edit, not by a script. See restrictions: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

Comment: What you can do is to give your timestamp script a different name, e.g. `function MyTimeStamp()` and call it inside `function myButton1()` with `MyTimeStamp();` at the end of the function. It will be called automatically, each time after a user presses a buton.

Comment: Is it complicated to set up the myButton1() function to write the time (hh:mm:ss) in column J in addition to the date change in column I "Last Check"?

Comment: No, it's not. You can do it analogously to changing the date, i.e.  assigning the range corresponding to column J to a variable (just like done for column I) and set a value to this range inside the inner `if`statement. As a value, use `new Date().toLocaleTimeString();`  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaletimestring.asp

Comment: Hello again :) I tried to change the code, but now I get an error called: There must be a name after "." operator. (Line 19, file "ChangeDate")
This is my variable: 
var rangeTimestamp=tickerCheck.getRange(startRow,10,lastRow,1);

and this I placed under the last element of the inner IF statement:

rangeTimestamp.new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

Comment: It should be `rangeTimestamp.getCell(i+1, 1).setValue(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());` Have a look at the following references about how to use Apps Script methods: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer)

Comment: Hello, I'm back with one more question :). Is there a possibility that the button script reads the UserID from the line in which the button is located? So I wouldn't have to duplicate the script for every User ID.